# Bus error caused while reading in a string

Tags: c

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 char *input = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
 input = "\0";

 while (1){
  scanf("%s\n", input);

  if (strcmp(input, "0 0 0") == 0) break;

  printf("%s\n",input);
 }

}
```

I'm trying to read in a string of integers until "0 0 0" is entered in.
The program spits out bus error as soon as it executes the scanf line, and I have no clue how to fix it.
Below is the error log.

```html
[1]    59443 bus error
```

Comment: `input = "\0";` is wrong. Replace with `input[0] = '\0';`.

Comment: this line: 'input = "\0";' places the address of "\0" into input, thereby overlying the address returned from malloc.  this results in a memory leak.  and the code should free() the pointer returned from malloc before exiting, and the returned value from malloc, in C, should not be cast, and the returned value from malloc should be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: 'scanf("%s\n", input);' is trying to write to where ;input' points, however, at that point in the code it is pointing to the read-only literal "\0"  That is why the buss error, but not the root cause of the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `input` to point to the first element of a string literal (while leaking the recently allocated buffer):

```
input = "\0"; // now the malloc'd buffer is lost
```

Then you try to modify said literal:

```
scanf("%s\n", input);
```

That is undefined behaviour. You can't write to that location. You can fix that problem by removing the first line, `input = "\0";`.

Next, note that you're only allocating space for one character:

```
char *input = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Once you fix the memory leak and the undefined behaviour, you can think about allocating more space. How much space you need is for you to say, but you need enough to contain the longest string you want to read in plus an extra character for the null terminator. For example,

```
char *input = malloc(257);
```

would allow you to read in strings up to 256 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem, (thanks to another answer) is that you're initializing `input` wrong, by pointing it at read-only data, then later trying to write to it via `scanf`. (Yes, even the lowly literal "" is a pointer to a memory area where the empty string is stored.)

The next problem is semantic: there's no point in *trying* to initialize it when `scanf()` will soon overwrite whatever you put there. But if you *wanted* to, a valid way is input[0] = '\0', which would be appropriate for, say, a loop using `strcat()`.

And finally, waiting in the wings to bite you is a deeper issue: You need to understand `malloc()` and `sizeof()` better. You're only allocating enough space for one character, then overrunning the 1-char buffer with a string of arbitrary length (up to the maximum that your terminal will allow on a line.)

A rough cut would be to allocate far more, say 256 chars, than you'll ever need, but `scanf` is an awful function for this reason -- makes buffer overruns painfully easy especially for novices. I'll leave it to others to suggest alternatives.

Interestingly, the *type* of crash can indicate something about what you did wrong. A Bus error often relates to modifying read-only memory (which is still a mapped page), such as you're trying to do, but a Segmentation Violation often indicates overrunning a buffer of a writable memory range, by hitting an unmapped page.

Comment: Technically my answer's wrong because I misread: `input = "\0"` as: `strcpy(input, "");` but if the incorrect assignment is removed, you'll still run into the bug provided by my analysis.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it's hard trying to understand all these coming from Python background.

Comment: So fix your answer, no?

Comment: Fixed and for reference on overruns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Security

Comment: Perhaps we're quibbling about semantics, but how so? Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Because the amount allocated has nothing to do with the error. The problem is writing to the location of a string literal.

Comment: The statements in the first paragraph are true, and helpful. So I might say tangential, but not wrong. Will rearrange.

Comment: THe statements in the first paragraph are wrong, and unhelpful, and may have confused OP and whoever up-voted your answer. You claim the allocated buffer is being overrun. It isn't, by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: There is point in trying to initialize it, because then if `scanf` fails and the code goes on to reads the contents of the buffer, it will see the previously-set default instead of accessing indeterminate values.

Comment: As Juan said your answer is misleading. He is assigning the char pointer to a string literal and causing a memory leak then trying to write to read only memory. Actually I tend to wonder why he even needs to dynamically allocate memory within this scope. Best avoided if unnecessary.  And advise using fgets rather than scanf. .. its much simpler to avoid problems that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = "\0";
```

is wrong.

**'input' is pointer, not memory.**

**"\0" is string, not char.**

You assigning pointer to a new value which points to a segment of memory which holds constants because "\0" is constant string literal.

Now when you are trying to modify this constant memory, you are getting bus error which is expected.

In your case i assume you wanted to initialize 'input' with empty string.
Use

```
input[0]='\0';
```

note single quotes around 0.

Next problem is malloc:

```
char *input = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

you are allocating memory for 1 character only.

When user will enter "0 0 0" which is 5 characters + zero you will get buffer overflow and will probably corrupt some innocent variable.

Allocate enough memory upfront to store all user input. Usual values are 256, 8192 bytes it doesn't matter.

Then,

```
scanf("%s\n", input);
```

may still overrun the buffer if user enters alot of text. Use fgets(buf, limit(like 8192), stdin), that would be safer.